# When to call the JobScheduler?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I want to call a method once every day to spawn the zombies in my app.

The following method should create a  JobScheduler that does this.

My question is: Do I call this method once or can I call it everytime at the startup of the app?

```
public static void startZombieSpawnService(Context context) {
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    long intervaloDeRepeticao = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
    jobScheduler.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(1, new ComponentName(context, ZombieSpawnService.class)).setPeriodic(intervaloDeRepeticao).setp.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission, then you can also use setPersisted(true) from JobInfo.Builder(). Then you only need to call it once and it will persist across reboots too.

Otherwise, when your app starts, you can check if your job is scheduled using this function:

```
public static boolean isJobScheduled(Context mContext, int jobID) {   
    JobScheduler mScheduler = (JobScheduler)
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    for (JobInfo jobInfo : mScheduler.getAllPendingJobs()) {
        if (jobID == jobInfo.getId()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If it is not scheduled, then schedule it.